# Backlink building for multiple local businesses in same industry

Tags: backlinks, local-seo, link-building

**First, some prefacing which I believe will help give important context to my question.**

All of our clients' sites (150+ of them) have a few things in common:

- They're all in the same field.
- They're local businesses.
- Lead gen sites only, with no e-commerce.
- In part because of these things, they tend to be very low monthly traffic. I would wager that for any of them above 1,000 hits a month (which is very few of them), the great majority of their hits will be non-local, non-leads. Since we're lead-gen only, this traffic is very low priority to us.
- Our clients use templated websites and content. Duplicate? Yes; however we've done some testing and have found that we don't lose traffic as a result of this. We suspect it's because the sites' focuses are so heavily localized.

This industry has some major players in the medical field who tend to produce popular content for queries at the top of the conversion funnel; we don't try to compete with these and instead focus almost entirely on bottom-of-the-funnel traffic.

**Here's my question:** What are some best practices for link building in a situation like this? Ordinarily, the general strategy might include generating great quality content, building a network with high authority sites, etc. However this seems to go out the window when we're looking at trying to do this for 150+ sites.

Our standard approach is to work with local partners and affiliates to build a network. We've had some success with this, although it has some lower, finite limitations than a more global business would have.

Comment: Do the sites link to each other at all?   If not, would doing so be appropriate for users?

Comment: They do not. Aside from being geographically in separate markets, they would otherwise be competitors with each other. The company I work for does have a microsite that links to each of them (sort of a directory/find a provider service) but individually they're exclusively independent from one another.

Answer (score 1):

Consider how you can integrate with the local market and exchange traffic and general good feelings with other businesses in the area. And here are some great ways to create backlinks:

- Look at larger websites in your industry. Start by sharing some of their content. Look for content where you could add a local angle, ask the site for a guest post, they might be more receptive if you offer to write the post for them.
- Sponsor meetup groups so your sites are seen on the meetup site, plus look for untapped businesses there who could provide mutual links.
- Host community events to get links from your city’s official website and prominent community news sources.
- Build and promote local resources to earn backlinks from suppliers and professionals in the local healthcare industry.

Answer (score 0):

start Creating local places pages on Google, Bing and Yahoo. Online citations and reviews might also help. You can also try running an AMA on Reddit (within a relevant subreddit)and within other local communities. Well, if all your clients are in the same market with same product and services, then you may be having a potential conflict.

Comment: Local pages have been part of our strategy, and I agree that's a good method. We're not in the same market exactly, but in some cases they're very close geographically (let's say there's a 100 mile buffer radius in most situations).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Focus on Keyword Research than anything else. Because if you don't choose right keywords for your business then you cant do well but efforts remain too much. 
But with Right Keywords, you can compete with big giants with fewer Backlinks.

Then On page SEO. (Your 70% Game depends upon these 2 points)

Then start Backlinks.

the Best Strategy for this is Copying Competitors BL Profile. it is the Easiest and best method to save time and Efforts.

Outreach Also another best method. use Ahrefs for Backlinks (broken, new, Competitors and everything)

You can also exchange Links with your clients where they don't compete with each other and with their permission.

Google+, tweets also helps you.